Reversed Fubini's
Assume we have a real valued function $F:\mathbb{R}^{n} \times (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$.
And assume that we have the function $ g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R} $ given by
$$
g(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} F(x,r) dr 
$$
Is Lebesgue measurable. can we conclude that $ F $ is also (n+1)-Lebesgue measurable as a function of $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n+1}$ ?
If it helps, we have that $g \in L^{r}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for some $ r \in (0,\infty)$.

Let $A\subset [0,1]$ be not Lebesgue measurable
Define
$$
f(x,r) = \chi_{ [0,1] \setminus A} (x) + 2 \chi_A(x) \chi_{[0,1/2]}(r).
$$
Then
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x,r)dr = \chi_{[0,1]}(x),
$$
however $f$ is not jointly measurable, as $f(x,r) = 1 - \chi_A(x)$ for all $r\in (1/2,1)$. This function (as function of $x$) is not measurable for all $r$ on the set $(1/2,1)$, which has positive measure.
